# file upload using robot class in selenium works fine on remote machine but fails when the remote connection is closed

Tags: java, file-upload, selenium-webdriver, remote-server

i have created a script for file upload using Robot Class in Selenium webdriver. It works fine, the script executes as expected. Now the automation set up is done on the server and a job is scheduled on jenkins to execute it periodically. The scripts executes fine when the remote desktop connection is kept open , but the file upload fails when the connection is minimized/terminated.
Could someone help on this ? why the robot api is unable to locate the element when the remote connection is minimized/terminated.

It would be helpful if you could provide other options to perform this file upload on remote server

Following is the HTML code :

```
<label ng-if="comp.allowmultiple!=1" ng-click="bind_click(comp.code,comp.allowmultiple)" id="singleupload_label" class="browse ng-scope" ng-show="canShow(comp.code, comp.allowmultiple)">Click to Browse

<input name="file_upload" data-code="332" id="singleupload" class="inputStyle fixview filingUpload hidden " type="file">
```

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
Thread.sleep(10000);
robot.mouseMove(2,130);
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
Thread.sleep(5000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input type is file i.e.

```
<input type="file" id="upload">
```

You can directly take use of `SendKeys`

```
driver.findElement(By.id("upload")).sendKeys("File Path");
```

Comment: Should i try this after click action or just this ? Because without click when I tried this it did not perform any action.

Comment: If the input `type=file`, you can directly use this.

Comment: I tried this                       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@id='singleupload_label']/input[@id='singleupload']")).sendKeys(strFileName); but its not uploading document and the script says it passed.

Comment: try 

`driver.findElement(By.id("singleupload")).sendKeys(new File(strFileName).getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: I tried this , it does not upload the file and it is not failing in this step too. It goes to the next command in which the element appears only after file upload so the next step fails. Following is the error - org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.name: file_desc.

Comment: hey this works for me in chrome, but failing in firefox.  following is the code driver.findElement(By.id("singleupload_label")).click();
WebElement upload = driver.findElement(By.id("singleupload"));
upload.sendKeys(strFileName); Could someone help me ??